# How plot results from a pairwise.wilcox.test?

Tags: r

I would like to plot a bubble/circle plot of p.values generated from pairwise comparisons. The goal is to be able to visually identify which comparisons are significant p < .05

For example like the one generated from corrplot.  The issue I think its because the table that it generates is not complete in that it lacks the full.  For example for a comparison for May-Sept the table looks like this.  Here is is my attempt to plot this with corrplot?

```
 library ( corrplot)
    attach(airquality)
    Month <- factor(Month, labels = month.abb[5:9])
    ## These give warnings because of ties :

    test = pairwise.wilcox.test(Ozone, Month, p.adj = "bonf")
    detach()

    corrplot(as.matrix (test$p.value), 
p.mat = as.matrix (test$p.value) ,  is.corr = FALSE, method = "circle", mar = c(1, 1, 2, 0) )
```

The table the pairwise generate looks like this.

```
> test$p.value
            May       Jun         Jul        Aug
Jun 1.000000000        NA          NA         NA
Jul 0.000299639 0.1413625          NA         NA
Aug 0.001208078 0.2590776 1.000000000         NA
Sep 1.000000000 1.0000000 0.007442604 0.03247955
```

is there a way to plot this similar to corrplot? Or any other way to show only significant comparison would be great.

thanks!

Comment: What about something like `data.frame(test$p.value) %>% rownames_to_column() %>% pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% mutate( sig = case_when(value < 0.05 ~ 'significant', TRUE ~ '')) %>% ggplot() + geom_tile(aes(rowname, name, fill = sig)) + scale_fill_manual(values = c('white', 'red')) + guides(fill=FALSE) + coord_equal() + theme_minimal()` ?

Comment: A `corrplot` is not really appropriate since it shows the strength of the relationship between two variables. Bigger is better. For p-values bigger is worse and smaller is better. Pairwise differences in ANOVA are typically plotted by showing the confidence interval for each comparison. For example: `plot(TukeyHSD(aov(Ozone~month.name[Month], airquality)))`

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @dcarlson, your main problem is that significant p-values are small, which is the other way around than expected by `corrplot`.

So a fairly simple trick is to transform the p-values, so that larger values correspond to more-significant.  A commonly-used way to do this is to take the negative of the log (this works nicely, since all p-values are less than one, so all log(p-values) are negative).

```
my_transformed_pvals=-log10(test$p.value)
corrplot(as.matrix(my_transformed_pvals),is.corr=F)
```

[image]

Comment: yes this is almost there. I did the same thing recently - I also just converted all the NA and > .05 to 0, however the order is and missing column is problematic.  For example the columns should contain all the variable and in the same order as the row, so it should be column may and start with may row.. and so on.  I can't seem to get this to work like that though ;(